# WP7 page seems alive

Tags: windows-phone-7

I read that WP7 uses backstack to represent the back navigation of the application.

In my application, there are 2 pages

1. Page 1: There are local variable int count1, and DispatcherTimer
   timer1
2. Page 2: There are local variable int count2, and DispatcherTimer
   timer2

timer1's callback in page1 is used to log count1++ value

timer2's callback in page2 is used to log count2++ value.

**Question 1** 
In page 1, I start timer1, then navigate to page2.

I thought page1 is pushed to the backstack and it is deactive. But the timer1 still runs with count1 incremented ??

**Question 2** In page2, I start timer2 and back to page1.

I thought page2 is dispose. But the timer2 still runs with count2 incremented?

Comment: Why downvote me? I have very clear stated question and I want to know the page mechanism in WP7, because it affects my application strongly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page may not be in view, but it is still running - just not drawing onto the screen. Any variables you have will still exist when you return to the page. Similarly, anything like a DispatcherTimer, will continue to exist, *and* continue to tick until you stop it.

An immediate issue is if you aren't saving a reference to your timer - if you don't, you won't be able to stop it! anyway, something like this would work:

```
protected void override OnNavigatedFrom(Object sender, NavigationEventArgs e){
    if (myTimer != null){ timer.Stop();}
    e.OnNavigatedFrom(sender,e);
}

protected void override OnNavigatedTo(Object sender, NavigationEventArgs e){
    //create, or turn on your timer, etc.
    e.OnNavigatedTo(sender,e);
}
```

The idea is basically how you describe: When leaving the page, 'pause' the timer. When you come back, turn the timer back on.

For Question 2:

When you create a timer, the *variable* to it may be local, but the `event` created from the timer is global - you will need to `dispose` of it when you're done with it. And that means not not only stopping it, but removing the event itself -

```
myTimer.Tick -= onTimerTick; // where onTimerTick is the name of your Event
```

Finally,

When your app gets `Deactivated`, your timer is stopped and killed. You should make sure to restart / recreate any timers that you have for when this happens. And if you're keeping *count* of something, remember to store the count so that you can keep track of where the user left off.

Comment: thanks. Your answer satisfies quesiton 1. But in quesiton 2, I think that page2 should be disposed, but timer2 can still uses count2 ?

Comment: @Yamamoto added a bit more info - let me know if you need more information. :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I think when back to page1, page2 must be killed, and count2 is killed too, but timer2 can still uses count2 ??

Comment: That is because it still maintains a reference to it, so the object (and potentially the entire page) is still stored in memory.